# Use a variable when adding text to a file bash

Tags: bash, touch

I have just recently started coding in bash, as in this is my first week. I am trying to create a program to automate the process of creating an executable .jar file for my java programs, and I am running into difficulties creating the manifest. I know that the manifest file needs to have "Main-Class: name".  The user inputs class, but then how can I add this to the manifest file. I have tried `touch "Main-Class: $name" > Manifest`, but this results in error.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `echo "Main-Class: $name" > Manifest`

Comment: @ode2k This worked! Thank you very much and I'm sorry it's such a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`echo "Main-Class: $name" > Manifest`

instead of `touch`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *here-doc* :

```
name="ZupaMasterMegaClass"

cat<<EOF>Manifest
Main-Class: $name
foo
bar
base
EOF

cat Manifest
```